# Get column content from one table and use it to get id from other table

Tags: mysql

Sorry for the bad description, not sure what to call this.

I'm trying to migrate a bad database structure to a better one.
The old storage, lets say customer name in say invoice table.
The new I going to need a ref to customer-table so that more information about the customer can be queried if needed.

So, to not completely break all the old entries, I would like a query that take col2,col3,col4 from tbl1 and and queries tbl2,tbl3 and tbl4 to get and ID of
each of the content of the columns.

Then I would want to update the row in tbl1 with these ID's in their respectable column.

The thing is, I have no idea about how to do this.
I don't even know what to search for to learn about it.

Better example:

Imagen you have pet-owner table. The old table had:

```
Owner: John 
pet: Dog
```

But now I have a table for owners and a table for pets, so I want to update the columns in pet-owner table so for each row it will (in this case) search ower-table for 'John' and pet-table for 'dog' and return their ID and update the pet-owner table with that.

Comment: I think you're going to have to do a bit better than this

Comment: It sounds like you are wondering how to do an `update` that joins multiple tables?  Some more concrete examples of your data might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have a much easier time if you add new columns to hold the ids, populate them, and then drop the old columns later.

If you do that, your `update` would be like:

```
update pet_owner
inner join pet on pet_owner.pet_name = pet.name
inner join owner on pet_owner.owner_name = owner.name
set pet_owner.pet_id = pet.id
    pet_owner.owner_id = owner.id
;
```

Comment: Yes, this looks to be somewhat right.
Imagen you have pet-owner table:
old table had:
Owner: John
pet: Dog

But now I have a table for owners and a table for pets,
so I want to update the columns in pet-owner table so for each row
it will (in this case) search ower-table for 'John' and pet-table for 'dog'
and return their ID and update the pet-owner table with that.

Your query looks to do so, i'm not just sure.
Don't really want to test it right now and risk messing up 700k rows on my test server. Takes a while to drop the tables and re-import everything :-)

Comment: I think I understand now.  I updated my answer to use that example; could you update your question with that info also?

Comment: All the 'inner join' got me all confused before, but now I see how it works.
The question has also been updated.
Thanks!